# Back on incorrect tab inside tablayout with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

Here is the flow of my app.

[image]

Step to product the bug.

- Open the app, the first screen would be Fragment A1
- Go to Fragment A2 from A1
- Tap on Tab B which is Fragment B1
- Go to Fragment B2 from B1
- Tap on Tab A (Screen shows A2)
- * Tap on **BACK**, screen do not change. If I tap on Tab B, I can see the screen back to B1.

Any way to fix if I tap **BACK** on A2, I can go back to A1.

BTW, I check `getBackStackEntryCount()` on A2 and B2. I can see that the final backStackEntryCount is 2.

Below is my code

From A1 to A2 or B1 to B2

```
ChildVC childFrag = new ChildVC();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameChildFragment, childFrag)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

Comment: you need to add tag or id in addToBackStack("childFrag")  and use .replace(R.id.frameChildFragment, childFrag) instead .add(R.id.frameChildFragment, childFrag)

Comment: How can I deal with the tag? And, I guess add also OK? cuz it just save the data.

Comment: see my answer to handle tag

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
Fragment currentFragment;
```

for pushing the fragment :

```
public void pushFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack, boolean shouldAnimate, Bundle bundle) {

        currentFragment = fragment;

        if (bundle != null) {
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        }
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        if (shouldAnimate) {
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
        if (addToBackStack) {
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        }

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container dataView with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getCanonicalName());



        // Commit the transaction
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
```

for pop fragment :

```
public void popBackFragment() {

        try {
            int backStackCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();

            if (backStackCount > 1) {

                FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backStackEntry = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(backStackCount - 2);

                String className = backStackEntry.getName();

                Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(className);

                currentFragment = fragment;

                fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            } else {

                  finish();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, we just need 1 container? which should be set in activity?

Comment: we need one container and it should be framelayout

Comment: yes... in activity, but you can use this for other container too, you need to pass one more params for that in push method

Comment: Oh God. I have container for each fragment. Let me try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169763/discussion-between-hitesh-sarsava-and-pak-ho-cheung).